# Android Nested Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use `nested fragments` in `ViewPager` but there's a problem. I have a `ViewPager` and on the first Page I want to add 3 `fragments`, that are responsible for taking picture and previewing it. 
Here's my full code:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

**PlaceHolderFragment layout, fragment_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frm1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frm2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frm3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

Here are `SectionPagerAdapter` and `Page Fragment` (`PlaceHolderFragment`) included.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

private ArrayList <Fragment> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initFragments();

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), list);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount());
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
private void initFragments(){
    list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    Fragment f = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        f = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i);
        f.setArguments(args);
        list.add(f);
    }
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Fragment> list;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> list) {
        super(fm);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        int pagePosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        if(pagePosition == 0){
            FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            TestImgFragment frg1 = new TestImgFragment();
            trans.add(R.id.frm1, frg1, "test1");
            TestImgFragment frg2 = new TestImgFragment();
            trans.add(R.id.frm2, frg2, "test2");
            TestImgFragment frg3 = new TestImgFragment();
            trans.add(R.id.frm3, frg3, "test3");
            trans.commit();
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Fragment f = null;
        f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("test1");
        f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("test2");
        f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("test3");
        f.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

}
```

And this is `Nested Fragment class` and `layout`:

**test_img_fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="@dimen/textLabel_weight"
    android:textSize="@dimen/view_text_size_normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="@dimen/inputView_weight"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/imageview_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/imageview_height"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/customview_marginright"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**TestImgFragment:**

```
public class TestImgFragment extends Fragment {
public static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Loan Images";
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_img_fragment, container, false);

    imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void openDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_image_setting_type);
    dialog.setTitle("Image Type");

    Button captureImage = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.capture);
    Button pickImage = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pick);

    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            captureImage();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    pickImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pickImage();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

private void captureImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void pickImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void previewImage(Bitmap image){
    Bitmap bitmap = image;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    switch(requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
                previewImage(bitmap);
            } else if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "User Cancelled Image Capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Failed to capture Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
                previewImage(bitmap);
            }else if(resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "User Cancelled Image Capture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Failed to capture Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

What I want to be done is that when the user `clicks` the `ImageView`, he/she should `capture` or `pick image` and it should be previewed. 
**But the Problem is** that when I click the first `ImageView` (First `Nested Fragment`) everything works, but when I click the second and the third `ImageViews` (`Nested Fragments`) in `PlaceHolderFragmet`-s `onActivityResult` `Nested Fragments` aren't visible, when I call `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("test1");` or any other `tag`, it returns `null`.

I have no idea what I am missing.